# JQuery selector [name^="value"] which starts with an string followed by a variable is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"] not working.

```
$('[id^="editMe_" + 'id']').css("display","none");
```

Here 'editMe_' is a string and 'id' is a variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have not handled the quotes correctly. Use:

```
$('[id^="editMe_'+id+'"]').css("display","none");
```

also you can use `.hide()` instead of  `.css("display","none")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this corrected quotes:

```
$('[id^="editMe_'+id+'"]').css("display","none");
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g7yvngks/1/)